# How to use numpy apply_over_axes with lambda function?

Tags: python, numpy

How to use numpy apply_over_axes with lambda function?

This one:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)

print(a)

>>[[0 1 2]
>> [3 4 5]]

def method_name(x,axis=0):
    return lambda x: print(x) or x ** 2
np.apply_over_axes(method_name, a,0)
```

results in:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

Ommiting any parameters in the declaration of `method_name` results in:

```
TypeError: method_name() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

Comment: For a 2d array simply iterating on one axis is simpler and faster.  And using a lambda for side effects like print is bad style even if it works.

Comment: thanks for that input. But just for my curiosity it would be a pleasure to understand the correct syntax :-)

Comment: I was thinking more of `apply_along_axis`.  This `apply_over` is more obscure.

Comment: That's not a lambda function, it's a function returning a lambda function. just use `method_name = lambda x, axis: print(x) or x ** 2`

Comment: I think this comment would the best answer

Comment: `name=lambda ..,` is the format I use in my last 2 examples.

Comment: Yes, allright. But perhaps putting this information at the very beginning of your answer would make it a little bit faster to understand... :-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52728493/numpy-vectorize-functions-apply-over-axes-apply-along-axis

Answer (score 2):

I've helped with the other `apply` function more, so have had to look at the docs and experiment.

But look at what happens when we call your function:

```
In [185]: method_name(a,0)
Out[185]: <function __main__.method_name.<locals>.<lambda>(x)>
```

It returned the lambda function.  `apply` expects the function call to return an array, hence the complaint that it doesn't have a `ndim`.

Change the function:

```
def method_name(x,axis=0):
    l = lambda x: print(x) or x ** 2
    return l(x)
```

Now it works:

```
In [187]: np.apply_over_axes(method_name, a,0)
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]]
Out[187]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  4],
       [ 9, 16, 25]])
```

So it has called the `method_name` once, passing it `a`.  Your lambda prints `a` (as a side effect) and returns its square.

What if we provide 2 axes values?

```
In [188]: np.apply_over_axes(method_name, a,[0,1])
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]]
[[ 0  1  4]
 [ 9 16 25]]
Out[188]: 
array([[  0,   1,  16],
       [ 81, 256, 625]])
```

It's squared it twice!  For the 2nd call it passed as `x` the result from the first call.  The axes don't have to be unique or in order either: `np.apply_over_axes(method_name, a,[0,1,0,1])`

The docs illustrate it with `np.sum` as the function, and demonstrate the equivalence with `sum` using several axes.  Originally functions like `sum` took just one axis value.  In that case this `apply_over_axes` would have been a handy way of repeating the sum (instead of `np.sum(np.sum(a, 0),0)`).  But now functions like that take a list, so there's less need for this `apply_over_axes` function.

---

`cumsum` might be a better illustration than `sum`, since it returns an array of the dimensions, and doesn't take multiple axes:

sum vertically:

```
In [210]: np.cumsum(a,0)
Out[210]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 5, 7]])
```

and again across columns:

```
In [211]: np.cumsum(_,1)
Out[211]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  3],
       [ 3,  8, 15]])
```

Doing the same thing with `apply`:

```
In [212]: np.apply_over_axes(np.cumsum, a, [0])
Out[212]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 5, 7]])

In [213]: np.apply_over_axes(np.cumsum, a, [0,1])
Out[213]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  3],
       [ 3,  8, 15]])
```

---

or another:

```
In [229]: l = lambda a, axis: np.add.accumulate(a**2, axis)

In [230]: l(l(a,0),1)
Out[230]: 
array([[   0,    1,   17],
       [  81,  370, 1211]])

In [231]: np.apply_over_axes(l, a, [0,1])
Out[231]: 
array([[   0,    1,   17],
       [  81,  370, 1211]])
```

It may be more useful for a case where the function reduces the dimensions, such as a `reduce`:

```
In [236]: rl = lambda a, axis: np.add.reduce(a**2, axis)

In [237]: np.apply_over_axes(rl, a, [0,1])
Out[237]: array([[1211]])
```

`apply_over_axes` does an better job of keeping track of dimensions than nested calls:

```
In [239]: rl(rl(a,0),0)
Out[239]: 1211
In [240]: rl(rl(a,0)[None,:],1)
Out[240]: array([1211])
```