# numpy - vectorize functions: apply_over_axes / apply_along_axis

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I want to calculate the determinant of m*m subarrays of a m*m*n dimensional arrays, and would like to do this in a fast/more elegant way. The brute-force approach works:

```
import numpy as n

array=n.array([[[0.,1.,2.,3.],[2,1,1,0]],[[0.5, 0.5,2,2],[0.5,1,0,2]]])
detarray=n.zeros(4)
for i in range(4):
    detarray[i]= n.linalg.det(array[:,:,i])
```

I would have tried doing this with apply_along_axis, but I know this is only for 1D arguments to the function, and so I presume I can't get this to work.

However, I thought apply_over_axes should also work:

```
n.apply_over_axes(n.linalg.det, array, [0,1])
```

but this gives me an error:
"det() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)"

Does anyone know why this doesn't work? If this type of calculation is really not possible with apply_over_axes, is there a better way to do this rather than the for-loop?

Comment: Those apply functions don't eliminate loops, they just hide them.

Comment: `apply_over_axes` 'iterates' on a list of axes.  Not over an axis but over the dimensions.  Say you have a 3d array, and want to sum on axes 1 and 2.  Now `sum` takes a tuple, but say it didn't.  You'd have to sum on 2 and then on 1.

Comment: Ok - so essentially what I've tried would iterate over the first and then the second axis, which doesn't make sense because I'd like it to act on both axes at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizing the [transpose semantics of NumPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) for 3D arrays, you can simply pass the transposed array to [`numpy.linalg.det()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.det.html) as in:

```
In [13]: arr = np.array([[[0.,1.,2.,3.], 
                          [2, 1, 1, 0]], 

                         [[0.5, 0.5,2,2],
                          [0.5, 1, 0, 2]]])

In [14]: np.linalg.det(arr.T)
Out[14]: array([-1. ,  0.5, -2. ,  6. ])
```

---

Performance wise this approach seems to be **twice as fast** as the other approach of manually moving the axes using `numpy.moveaxis`

```
In [29]: %timeit np.linalg.det(np.moveaxis(arr, 2, 0))
12.9 µs ± 192 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [30]: %timeit np.linalg.det(arr.T)
6.2 µs ± 136 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: That's clever! (+1)

Comment: Btw. I checked `np.transpose(arr, (2, 0, 1))` and `np.transpose(arr, (2, 1, 0))` take the same time. So it's really just the overhead of `moveaxis` not the axis shuffling itself that makes the difference.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Perhaps it could be because `numpy.moveaxis` is implemented in plain Python and has a couple of `for` loops  as well. That could be the place it's hogging time.

Comment: Yep, will be a lot compared to the actual computation when arrays are so small.

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.linalg.det` is vectorized out of the box. All you need to do is move the outer axes to the left:

```
>>> np.linalg.det(np.moveaxis(array, 2, 0))
array([-1. ,  0.5, -2. ,  6. ])
```